Unable to load Arxiv PDF using Iframe
I am trying to load an Arxiv PDF file (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.14619.pdf) on a React application using iframe but getting the following error.
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/...' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but requested an insecure frame 'http://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.14619'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is happening even if I pass an HTTPS URL, which seems to be redirecting to HTTP version. Here is the CodePen. Any idea how to resolve this?
Thanks.

If you load https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.14619.pdf in your browser you'll notice it redirects to http://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.14619. At least, you can see that in FireFox, in Chrome however it further redirects to https://arxiv.org/pdf/2404.14619. Anyway, there is a redirect to http:// in there.
